# Prove a set to be measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\left\{f_{n}\right\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $R$ and let $f$ be a measurable function on $R$.Prove that $\left\{x\in R| \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_{n}\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)\right\}$ is measurable.

I know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f\left (x\right)$ is measurable,so it's sufficient for us to prove that given two measurable functions $f(x)$and $g(x)$,the set $\left\{x\in R |f(x)=g(x)\right\}$ is measurable. Then I don't know how to deal with that set.

Comment: Is the second line in the yellow part missing at its end the words "is measurable"?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\left\{x\in R |f(x)=g(x)\right\}=\left\{x\in R |f(x)-g(x)=0\right\}=(f-g)^{-1}\{0\}.$$
Questions for you:

- Is the singleton $\{ 0\}$ measurable?
- Is the sum/difference of measurable function measurable?

Once you have established the above, the claim follows by very definition of measurability.

Comment: Got it ,thank you for your hint.

Comment: You are welcome!